# Powershell: order of the Cmdlet Binding Attributes

Tags: powershell

a simple Function:

```
function Just-Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet('yes','no')]
        [string]$inputen,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]

        [ValidateScript(
        {
            if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -count 1 -quiet))
            {
                throw "no conn to server!"
            }
            else
            {
                $true
            }
        })]
        [ValidatePattern('^19')]
        [string]$comp
    )
}
```

Then I call the function:
Just-Test -inputen 'yes' -comp '172.168.0.1'

First: there is no computer '172.168.0.1', second: the pattern is wrong, so I get the error:
Just-Test : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'comp'. The argument "172.168.0.1" does not match the "^19" pattern. Supply an argument that matches "^19" and try the command again.

Then I change the code and put [ValidationPattern]  directly after ...Mandatory..:

```
function Just-Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet('yes','no')]
        [string]$inputen,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidatePattern('^19')]
        [ValidateScript(
        {
            if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -count 1 -quiet))
            {
                throw "no conn to server!"
            }
            else
            {
                $true
            }
        })]

        [string]$comp
    )
}
```

Of course I get an error:
Just-Test : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'comp'. no conn to server!
but the wrong pattern of the comp-name ('172...') would be totally ignored??
Why?

Comment: You might want to check the preview on your future questions because this is very difficult to read.

Comment: Why apply addition validators, when some already say, that argument does not value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would just use the last Validate attribute it sees, which would be why changing the order they are defined in would change the behavior. Really there's no reason you can't put both checks in the ValidateScript code if you are using that anyway.